# What is the difference between Desktop and Server?

Tags: server

Hi I have been using Ubuntu 8 and Ubuntu 15 for about a month now.

I wanted to know what is the point of getting a server edition.  What does it mean?

Thanks for the answers, Yo and yes there is to an Ubuntu 8, I installed in on my computer. Whatever doesn't matter. AND actually I installed LUbuntu 15 not Ubuntu. The first response to my question wasn't really the point.  I kinda found the answer lower on the page but that just helped me decide if I should use a server addition.  Oye!

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu 8 and Ubuntu 15".  The current version of Ubuntu is 15.04 which came out in april of 2015.  8.04 came out in april of 2008 and is no longer supported, 8.10 came out in october 2008, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Server version of Ubuntu comes without any desktop graphical environment.

Only with command line interface. It can't be used as a desktop computer in the common meaning of these words.

But desktop environment can be installed later.

**Short answer:** If you plan to use graphical interface, do NOT install a server version. Except some special cases when normal system does not install.